# How can I print "Done" or "Fail" at the end of line to stdout in Perl?

Tags: perl, printing, stdout, end-of-line

I just have begun with Perl and I want to write my own script to scan a document and convert the resulting TIFF file to a PDF file. If the conversion succeeds (using [`tiff2pdf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tiff2pdf)), I want to print "Done" at the end of the line, but I can't seem to find a hint to do this on the Web.

My guess is that I have to get the geometry of the terminal and count the letters I already printed but that seems to be to complicated. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Are you outputting the PDF source to stdout or to a named file?  Have you tried just `print "Done\n";`?  Can you explain more what you are trying to do and what you are getting instead?

Comment: Do you mean the end of the line or at the side of the terminal window? Those mean different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about having to inspect the size of the terminal you're printing to. There's many ways to do that, but the most portable and reliable way I'm aware of is [`Term::Size::Any`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aSize%3a%3aAny).

With that, you can get the width of the terminal you're running in:

```
use Term::Size::Any;
my $cols = chars *STDOUT{IO};
```

With that, you can then print whatever you want, padded with the right amount of whitespace, e.g.:

```
printf "% ${cols}s", "Done\n";
```

Also be aware that programs don't always output to terminals. Output could, for example, be redirected to a file, so you might want to have an appropriate fallback if determining the terminal size fails.